# Hiding css source code in style.css

Tags: css, wordpress, stylesheet

I noticed some WP websites have their style.css file almost empty when you open the link through the source code view. 
For instance, only these lines appears.

```
/*
Theme Name: xxxx
Author: xxx
Author URI: http://xxxx.com
Description: 
Version: 1.0.0
*/

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    outline:none;
}
```

How can I do the same?
Thx for your help.

Comment: It's not hiding, but including the CSS as separate files.

Answer (score 0):

They most probably include other CSS files that include other styles, as the example you've given above is a simple CSS reset, that removes all margins, paddings and outlines from **every** html element. It's essentially the same as starting with a blank piece of paper, removing all the lines.

So now you can add your own custom CSS file, and not need worry about any parent declarations that could affect it.

The proper way to add CSS files to Wordpress, is via your functions file.

Create another CSS file somewhere, and then enqueue the new file within the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook. Note: You should search your functions file to see if this hook is already in there, as you shouldn't just copy and paste this into your file if it is.

```
function load_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet', get_stylesheet_uri() ); // Your existing style.css file
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-css', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/custom.css', array('stylesheet'); // Your new css file, with path, and dependency, so it loads AFTER the original stylesheet
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts' );
```

Comment: I'll just add that this reset (and any reset in generally) is a very bad thing to do.  A CSS base like normalize.css is generally a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you are asking how to hide source of a CSS file and still have it being used by browser.
Couple of things here and you can (should) read about these more

1. You should know how style.css works in wordpress and its purpose in wordpress theme culture
2. You should know about minification and how it can help or cause problems if you are creating CSS which you dont want to copy or you are copying someone else CSS file but cant make sense of it.

First style.css in wordpress start with theme info so each Theme can pickup its meta data from this file. It can be completely non-CSS with only top comment in there for theme info. Wordpress has other ways of registering CSS and JS files in header and footer that you can use and these can be viewed via various tools like Developer Tools.

Second minification is a process to reduce file size by introducing various checks for example extra spaces, combining rules or making variable names small. Some of these rules make CSS files unreadable to humans but they do make sense to browser. So you might see a jumbled CSS file in source but some browsers like chrome can UNjumble it for you when you inspect element.

To answer your question the author of theme has placed those lines in css file and stored it with theme however the rest of css is in other files which are queued in head or bottom of actual page. It is also possible that theme may not require much css and uses default browser CSS or it is in-line. There are some crazy people living without css as well.

**How can you do it?**

In your theme use [this technique](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) to add other files and if you want you can copy all css from theme into another file called blabla.css and put it in your theme folder and remove all css from style.css except the theme meta data. Enqueue it and style.css will appear empty while blabla.css will have all css.